# C# Entity Framework - Long String not being persisted as NVARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am very new to C# and I'm developing a small application to test the code-first approach on Entity Framework.

My application has a class Download which contains the following properties:

```
[Key]
public int DownloadId { get; set; }
public string URL { get; set; }
public Boolean IsFinished { get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
public string Contents { get; set; }
```

In my Main method I create some HTTP GET requests to several web pages and insert their response into the Contents column using a DbContext:

```
//Persist the download first without contents, just the URL
context.Downloads.Add(d);
context.SaveChanges();


// Create request
request = WebRequest.Create(d.URL);
request.Method = "GET";

response = request.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();

d.Contents = responseFromServer;
Console.WriteLine("d.Contents= " + d.Contents);
context.SaveChanges();
```

It works perfectly for most pages. Whenever the page is a bit bigger ,though (which means a longer string), the Contents are empty.

I tested the contents of the string (see one line before last, above) and I got the complete contents of the web page, which means the problem is exactly on the last line (contexto.SaveChanges()). In other words, a have a relatively large string which should be persisted to an NVARCHAR(MAX) column and for some reason it is not being persisted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the value of the stirng which is not persisted correctly.

Comment: Have you tried saving a big string generated by your own? e.g. `new string('a', 20000)`

Comment: Please post the Table definition you currently have in your database.

Comment: What about using `[MaxLength]` annotation?

Comment: helb: yes, I've isolated the problem and found out that I can persist a string of 43679 characters, but can't persist a string of 43680 characters.

Comment: sorry guys I've just found out what was wrong. it was actually two things that made it impossible to debug: (1) the download happened within a thread context; when the page was big I was querying the database before the download had finished and thus got an empty reply; (2) the Server Explorer in Visual Studio doesn't show the contentes of the NVARCHAR(MAX) column if it's longer than 43679 bytes, even if the data is there.

Comment: I found the solution by adding a Thread.sleep(10000) after the insert, and then querying the database and writing to the console. Server Explorer still doesn't show the contents, but in these 10 seconds the web page is persisted into the db.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: ErikEJ: SQL Server 2012. I found the solution (see the two comments above), I still can't post it as the answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. The Server Explorer in Visual Studio doesn't show the contentes of the NVARCHAR(MAX) column if it's longer than 43679 bytes, even if the data is there.

Also, the download happened within a thread context; when the page was big I was querying the database before the download had finished and thus got an empty reply.

Comment: I found the same to be true with SQL Server Management Studio. The Results tab did not show the full contents of the NVARCHAR(MAX) column. But saving the results to a CSV file did show that the full string was saved to the database successfully.